# Problems formatting a string - Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm coming across a little weirdness with the str.format() method and wondered if there might be a workaround.

Here is a basic example of the problem I am facing:

```
'something {first.alpha} something {last}'.format(**{'first.alpha':'then', 'last':'else'})
```

I would expect this to return:

```
"something then something else"
```

but instead I get this error:

```
 KeyError: 'first'
```

I'm aware that there are other approaches for formatting a string, but until now this approach seemed like the perfect fit for what I needed.

The following example works perfectly, but it is important that the 'first.alpha' key exists.

```
'something {first} something {last}'.format(**{'first':'then', 'last':'else'})
```

Is there a way that I might still be able to use the str.format() method and contain fullstops within a key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you use named arguments in `format` would be something like this

```
>>> 'something {first_alpha} something {last}'.format(first_alpha = 'then', last = 'else')
'something then something else'
```

I wouldn't use `first.alpha` because then it thinks that `first` has an attribute `alpha`.

Comment: Ok cool... so a simple {k.replace('.','_'): v for k, v in dict.items()} should fix all the field_name's, as these are pre-generated, and I can update each of the replacement_fields myself. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `.` in placeholder names. Instead, `.` is part of the syntax to mean an *attribute lookup*. The format strictly limits keys to *valid Python identifiers*, which means they have to have at least 1 letter or underscore at the start.

From the grammar in the [*Format String Syntax* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
```

So the `field_name` is either an integer or a [valid Python identifier](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), and using a `.` means everything after is interpreted as an attribute.

You cannot work around this using `**{...}` syntax; stick to valid Python identifiers instead.